# PHP/MYSQL: UPDATE Statement containing carriage returns or new lines

Tags: php, mysql, carriage-return

I have some php script that is adding a new line to a string saved in MYSQL in a mychar field.

When I look at the database using mysqladmin, I can see fields that have multiple lines.  They do not show any characters.  Whatever is creating the new line is invisible.
[image]

However, when I try to update an existing string with a string that includes an extra line, using \n, it updates the field as empty.  I'm guessing this is because mysql does not accept \n in an update statement.

Can anyone suggest how to prepare a string in PHP so that when updating a field in MYSQL it updates properly, ie with new line.  \n does not seem to work.

```
$sql = "UPDATE comments SET comment = 'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline' WHERE id = 23"
```

When you run the above statement, it does update the line but the comment field is empty.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried to double escape your newlines? Try to replace `\n` with `\\n`.

Comment: Turn error reporting on. The error could be anywhere but not in this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is parsed 2 times: First by PHP and then my MySQL.
PHP replaces `\n` with the line feed character, but MySQL seems to ignore those whitespace characters. By double escaping `\n` to `\\n` you achieve, that the `\n` character sequences are parsed by MySQL and inserted as line feeds.

Comment: The following update statement rewrote the field as blank. UPDATE comments SET comment = 'First\\nSecond',lasttouched=now() WHERE id='2012'

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try like this

```
$data = 'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline';
    $sql = "UPDATE comments SET comment = $data WHERE id = 23"
```

Comment: If you want to make it that way you have to at least write `SET comment = '$data'`

Comment: The sql statement is built dynamically so I think I am already doing that. My actual code is: $strSet = '';
$strSet.="comment = '$comment',";
$strSet.="lasttouched=now(),";
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE comments SET ".$strSet;
//removes trailing comma
if (substr($sqlupdate, -1, 1) == ',')
{
  $sqlupdate = substr($sqlupdate, 0, -1);
}
$sqlupdate.= " WHERE id='$commentid' AND userid='$userid' ";
$sqlupdate.=" LIMIT 1";
$comment should be the equivalent of your $data

Comment: Of note, when I run the update query with single \ ie UPDATE comments SET comment = 'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline' WHERE id = 23 in the mysqladmin SQL window it runs without problem.

Comment: may i know what is the datatype of   comment